# How to make permanent marker displays the popup in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

Good afternoon, I'm adding a bookmark to OpenLayers with a popup, but I would like to make this marker is always active, not just hide in and it is not necessary to make click to display.

```
    // popup successful, but the click event is on
    marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(data.idunidad,
            marker.lonlat,
            new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
            '<p>Info HTML</p>',
            null,true);
        mapa.addPopup(popup);
    });
```

popup without mouse event

```
    // popup without mouse event
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(data.idunidad,
        marker.lonlat,
        new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
        '<p>Info HTML</p>',
        null,true);
    mapa.addPopup(popup);
```

in the latter I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

How should I do?

Comment: I found an example on the official website of OpenLayers http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html but when I try to leave it as in the example I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null | this error comes when the code enters mapa.addPopup (popup);

Comment: someone who can help me, please?